# RadioGroup not working in redux-form

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am using the custom radio button component in `redux-form`. I am not able to make it work properly. Following the custom component code.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Col,
  ControlLabel,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { RadioGroup, Radio } from 'react-radio-group';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './style.css';

const FormRadioGroup = props => (
  <FormGroup controlId={props.name || ''}>
    <Col
      componentClass={ControlLabel}
      sm={props.labelColValue || 2}
      className={props.labelClass || ''}
    >
      { props.label || 'Checkbox Label'}
    </Col>
    <Col sm={props.radioColValue || 6}>
      <RadioGroup
        name={props.name}
        selectedValue={props.input.value}
        onChange={value => { props.input.onChange(value); }}
        className="react-radio-group-button"
      >
        {
          _.map(props.options, option =>
            (
            <Label>
              <Radio value={option.key} />
              {option.value}
            </Label>
            ))
        }
      </RadioGroup >
    </Col>
  </FormGroup>
);

FormRadioGroup.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    labelColValue: PropTypes.number,
    labelClass: PropTypes.string,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    radioColValue: PropTypes.number,
    options: PropTypes.array,
    disabled: PropTypes.boolean,
    radioClass: PropTypes.string,
    sendBoolean: PropTypes.boolean,
    input: PropTypes.object,
    meta: PropTypes.object,
};

export default FormRadioGroup;
```

In `redux-form` I am using as follows.

```
<Field
      name="json_boolean_property"
      component={FormRadioGroup}
      format={value => (value ? 'yes':'no')}
      parse={value => (value === 'yes')}
      type="radio"
      labelColValue={2}
      label="Radio Group Label"
      radioBoxColValue={6}
      sendBoolean
      options={[
        { key: 'yes', value: 'Yes' },
        { key: 'no', value: 'No' },
      ]}
    />
```

I am not able to set the default value when it comes form the server also when i select the radio button it fire the change event but along with that it also give `redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS`.

I am not sure, what wrong I am doing but its failing very badly.